# Python count change in list for specific text

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, count

I'm trying to figure out how to count the change of status or string in a list.  For example here is a list ...

ABC
ABC
ABC
xyz
xyz
xyz
ABC
ABC
xyz
ABC

I want to keep count of the change from ABC to xyz.  So for this example the count would be 2 as it changed from ABC to xyz two times.

Thanks.

Comment: So what have you tried?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Also do you want to count change from xyz to ABC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [str.count](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) for that purpose. If you have to count `ABC` before `xyz` in a list you can join it and apply str.count method:

```
abc_list = ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'xyz' 'ABC']
abc_string = ''.join(abc_list)
print abc_string.count('ABCxyz')
```

Approrach above is simple, but it won't work if you have list like ['AB', 'C', 'xyz'], for such case you can simply make join on some string, and include that string into count:

```
abc_string = '!!!'.join(abc_list)
print abc_string.count('ABC!!!xyz')

counter = 0
for index, item in enumerate(abc_list):
  if index < len(abc_list) and item == 'ABC' and abc_list[index+1] == 'xyz':
    counter += 1
```

Comment: OP says input is a list, if it's actually a string (as you interpret) then just use `.count()`

Comment: Right. input is a list 'ABC', 'ABC, 'ABC', 'xyz' ..... I will try out what you folks are suggesting here. Thanks!!

Comment: @Chris_Rands thank you very match, really missed that .

Comment: Joining the list won't always work, e.g. if 1 list item is `'ABCxyz'` or consecutive items are `'AB'` and `'Cxyz'`

Comment: @Chris_Rands make sense, you can avoid it by splitting with some char, for instance '!!!' or by writing loop over list as proposed in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work:

```
counter = 0
for i in range(len(input_list) - 1):
    if input_list[i] == "ABC" and input_list[i + 1] == "xyz":
        counter += 1
```

Comment: This one for me only counted 1.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use the builtin `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

a = ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'xyz', 'ABC']

print {(k1, k2): val for (k1, k2), val in Counter([(a[i], a[i+1]) for i in range(len(a)-1)]).iteritems() if k1 != k2}

>>> {('ABC', 'xyz'): 2, ('xyz', 'ABC'): 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

SequenceMatcher from difflib seems to be a good tool for this.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

haystack = 'ABC ABC ABC xyz xyz xyz ABC ABC xyz ABC xyz ABC DCE ABC xyz'.split()
haystack_sz = len(haystack)

needle = ['ABC', 'xyz']
needle_sz = len(needle)

s = SequenceMatcher(None, needle, haystack)

m = s.find_longest_match(0, needle_sz, 0, haystack_sz)
print m # just for debug

count = 0

while m.size == needle_sz:
   count += 1
   m = s.find_longest_match(0, needle_sz, m.b + m.size, haystack_sz)
   print m # just for debug

print count
```